# how to extract the data from mysql database and plot them in highcharts using yii-framework

Tags: mysql, yii, highcharts

mysql database has three elements, id,datetime and data.

Please kindly help me check what is wrong with my code. i want to extract latest 15 data form mysql database and plot them in highcharts. however, i can only display latest single data on the graph beside my x-axis has not displayed datetime data.

i tried the codes provides on web http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic however it is only for predefined values and not for the mysql database values.

i tried to edit it and below is my code.

```
<script scr = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>       
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>    

</head>
<?php
$rowsA = array();
$rowsA[]= Yii::app()->db->createCommand("Select data from customername order by id desc limit 15")->queryScalar();
$datedata[] = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("Select date from customername order by id desc limit 15")->queryScalar();
>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
    },
        title: {
            text: 'BABY BODY TEMPERATURE',
            x: -20 
        },

        xAxis: {

       // type: 'datetime',
       // dateTimeLabelFormats:{
        //   month: '%e, %b',
          //  year: '%b'}//can work
     //  categories: ['<php echo join($datedata, "','") ?>'],
     // categories: [<php  echo join($datedata, "','"); ?>],
        //  },

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C',

    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Baby Temperature',
        data: [<?php echo join($rowsA, "','");?>]


        //predefined data is working fine.
       // data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
 });
});

</script>
```

i was thinking after i am able to extract mysql data and plot it in highcharts for x axis is in number forms 1,2,3,.... then i will try to display datetime in x axis. however, i was stucked at my first stage; can only display single latest data while what i want is 15 data.

I will be very appreciated if anyone can help me. Thanks a lot inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

Never query in your view file. Make getter in your model or query in controller and pass data to view.
For dates for x-label form array. For example i form array for last 30 days:

```
        $output = array();
        for($i = 30; $i >=0 ; $i--)
        $output[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
        return $output;
```

It will be our x-labels. Then get your data in model or controller:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->limit=15;
        $criteria->order='id DESC';
$data=new CActiveDataProvider(, array('customername'
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
```

Now form your array for series from your data.
Yii-highcharts is great extension that helps alot. 
Then push it to your plot:

```
'xAxis'=>array(
                'categories'=> $xlabels, 
                'gridLineWidth' => 1,
                'gridLineDashStyle' => 'LongDash',
                'tickmarkPlacement' => 'on',
                'tickInterval' => 6
                    ),

'series'=> array(

            array('name'=> 'Failed records',
                'data'=> $data_array,
                'color' => '#ff0000',
                'shadow'=> false
            ),
```

With yii-highcharts or echo php variables in javascript:

```
var xlabels="<?php echo $xlabels?>";
```

Then use it in your plot:

```
xAxis:{
                categories: xlabels, 
                gridLineWidth : 1,
                gridLineDashStyle : 'LongDash',
                tickmarkPlacement : 'on',
                tickInterval : 6
                    },
```

Comment: thanks alot for taking your valuable time to answer my question. :) i will try to work out with your methods and see how first. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Hi, would you mind to clarify ur answers abit more? my graph becomes empty now. i am so sorry. :(

Comment: Try to use http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/highcharts/. its a wrapper so you can use php to draw your chart. Emmpty plot means that: a)your data arrays are empty;b) you trying to feed series with not int values; c) you have errors in your statements. If you use classic highcharts on js you can push your code to jsfiddle. Try to read documentation wiki's.